# Crystal Reports Print Text on Last Page with no other information

Tags: crystal-reports

We are trying to modify a crystal report (estimate template) to print  some legalee jargon on the Last page of a crystal report. The last page would only have the text which we have in Group Footer 1b. Group Footer 1A has the totals of the document and should print after the details section. Currently the Page Header prints on the page with the Group Footer 1B text and we cannot seem to find a conditional format on how to exclude the page header from printing.

Can't use the report footer because we have multiple documents(estimates) which print at the same time.

Comment: I think I need a conditional formula on the Page Header to suppress when the Page Header # 1 B is present.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would put that information in the Report Footer.  The report footer will only print once at the end of the report.  If you want to make sure this information always has a page to itself, go into section expert, select Report Footer, then find the Paging tab (Not sure which version of CR you are using.  I'm using CR2008.  Layout might be different).  Check "New Page Before".  This will force a new page when it reaches the Report Footer.